# Android Studio - Gradle Build Failed could not get repositories, reseived status code 403: forbidden

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build an Android project after upgrading to the newest version of Android Studio (Giraffe 2022.3.1) but I am keep getting stuck at Gradle Sync with the following error for Google and JCenter repository downloads:

```
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl.android.maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.2/gradle-4.1.2.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

I am using gradle version 8.3

The computer I am working with is behind an internal company network but I have set up the CA certificates and not behind a proxy. I can also copy-paste the repository links to my browser and can download the files manually. What could be the reason that Android Studio cannot download from these repositories and how can I solve it.

Also, here is a screenshot of the build screen:

[image]